# How to find correlation between two columns of pandas dataframe of one column in float64 and other column is object(string)

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

In my case it is between sky condition and visibility

```
Skycondition visibility
 CLR.                 10SM
SCT103.              7SM
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have a nominal variable, you can't actually compute a correlation per se.  However, one way you may get some idea of the strength of the relationship between the variables is to define dummy variables for them and perform a series of multiple linear regressions.  E.g., assuming your data is in a dataframe called `data`, which I've reformatted slightly for clarity:

```
       Skycond   Vis
    0      CLR  10SM
    1   SCT103    7S
```

We then generate the dummy variables:

```
demo = pd.get_dummies(data)

       Skycond_CLR  Skycond_SCT103  vis_10SM    vis_7SM
    0            1               0         1          0
    1            0               1         0          1
```

And finally fit the linear regression models.  Here I'm choosing to compare the `Skycond_CLR` to the visibility variables:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LinearRegression

model.fit(demo[list(demo.columns[2:])],
          demo[demo.columns[0]])

print("Model slope:    ", model.coef_)
print("Model intercept:", model.intercept_)
```

Which gives:

```
Model slope:     [-0.33333333  0.33333333 -0.33333333]
Model intercept: 0.6666666666666666
```

Of course for just two samples, the regression doesn't tell you much.  As you add more data, the gradient coefficients will begin to indicate some relationship with the chosen dependent variable, which could be interpreted as a surrogate for a correlation.